# Someone is a .... user of a something, to say he is using it daily or a lot?

Tags: adjectives

Is it correct to refer to someone who is using something a lot, by '**a big user of ...**'. I'm talking here specially about software usage.
Is there an accurate word ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [**big**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/big) can be used to describe a user who uses a program a lot.

> 1.5 - Doing a specified action very often or on a very large scale

---

A second choice could be [**frequent**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/frequent) which would be a bit more formal.

> 1.1 - *[attributive]* (of a person) doing something often; habitual

---

A third choice could be [**heavy**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/heavy) which, like big, would be a little less formal.

> 3.2 - Doing something more, or more deeply, than usual.

---

If the person is an expert in all functions of the program they may also be called a [**Super User**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/superuser) (hence one of the most popular sites on SE being named that).

> A user of a computer system with special privileges needed to administer and maintain the system

Comment: A constant user.  A regular user.

Comment: 'Frequent' is different from 'heavy'. If I use the system for 1 minute every day, I'm a 'frequent' user, but possibly not a 'heavy' user. (Assuming that most people use it less frequently.) If I use it for a whole day every month I might be a 'heavy' user but not a 'frequent' user.

Comment: @GEdgar I think 'regular' is very close to the meaning of what I want to express.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is a 'big' user of something, it means they use it a lot. There isn't a specific frequency, or amount, of use that defines 'big', any more than there is a specific size that qualifies for the physical description 'big'.

Comment: What I'm looking for should be in professional context.

Comment: Everything I wrote in this answer applies in a professional context. If you need to consider an amount that they use the system, then you have to specify that amount.